# Text or source (preferably free) for learning developmental biology

Tags: development, book-recommendation

I might have to take a graduate level course in developmental biology, of which I have never taken a course in before. The course website lists no recommended texts. Therefore, I assume we will be doing a more independent study, and I would want to have a book or source to better facilitate that study.

Any recommendation, free or not free, is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gilbert's Developmental Biology is an excellent text. It is in the [11<sup>th</sup> edition](http://11e.devbio.com/), though the [6<sup>th</sup> edition](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9983/) is available free on NCBI bookshelf.

Comment: I ended up buying the 9th edition since I felt the 6th was too old, and I could not figure out how to access a .pdf form of the 6th. Thanks :D

Comment: @RoSiv Many free text books on NCBI are only accessible by searching. You can get into whole chapters/sections if you just search for the title. Of course, the actual book is much more user friendly; I hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

For a very quick and free introduction, you can have a look at [Khan Academy > Developmental Biology](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/developmental-biology).

Of course, before studying developmental biology, you will need basis in molecular biology and molecular genetics.

Comment: Yea I kind of found myself thrown into the whole grad school life. Just hoping to knuckle through.